# javascript doesn't work on Joomla 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, module

I always use jquery script directly to joomla's modules.

Lately, I switched from using Joomla2 to Joomla3. Somehow, scripts are not working anymore in  modules. Anybody knows why?

(some script still works though)

Example:
This is what I am working on.

```
<a href="#intro">Intro</a> <a href="#about">About</a> <a href="#info">Info</a>
<h1 id="intro">Intro</h1>
<p>abcd</p>
<h1 id="about">About</h1>
<p>xxxxxxxxxx</p>
<p>xxxxxxxxxx</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jump=function(e)
{
       //prevent the "normal" behaviour which would be a "hard" jump
       e.preventDefault();
       //Get the target
       var target = $(this).attr("href");
       //perform animated scrolling
       $('html,body').animate(
       {
               //get top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target
               scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
       //scrolldelay: 2 seconds
       },600,function()
       {
               //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
               location.hash = target;
       });

}

$(document).ready(function()
{
       $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
       return false;
});
</script>
```

The code gives a smooth scroll on targeted menu id.
If I use above code in Joomla2 module, it works great but doesn't work in Joomla 3.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you seeing any messages in your browser Javascript console? That is a good place to start looking for errors in this area.

Comment: Have you checked console for what is the error you are getting in js function?

Comment: Do you have see the javascript console ? May be have an error.

Comment: dont use joomla, dont use jquery 1.6

Comment: also, try `$('a[href*="#"]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mootools is loaded by default in Joomla! 2.5.x. It's an another JS library like jQuery they also use $ symbol. so we need to fix this issue using the jQuery.noConflict() method.

Try to use jQuery this way and recheck.

```
  var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
  // $jQ is now an alias to the jQuery function
  // creating the new alias is optional.

  $jQ(document).ready(function() {
   $jQ( "div" ).hide();
  });
```

I have rewritten your code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jump=function(e)
{
       //prevent the "normal" behaviour which would be a "hard" jump
       e.preventDefault();
       //Get the target
       var target = $jQ(this).attr("href");
       //perform animated scrolling
       $jQ('html,body').animate(
       {
               //get top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target
               scrollTop: $jQ(target).offset().top
       //scrolldelay: 2 seconds
       },600,function()
       {
               //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
               location.hash = target;
       });

}

var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();

$jQ(document).ready(function()
{
       $jQ('a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
       return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, This is great. It works now. Thank you very much. I am not very good at jQuery, so would you please explain me a bit of what happened with Joomla 3? And if I face similar problems, could i just use above code?

Comment: Mootools is loaded by default in Joomla! 2.5.x. It's an another JS library like jQuery they also use $ symbol. so we need to fix this issue using the jQuery.noConflict() method.